# Unable to parse array in JSON.parse in node

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am using node version 6.0.0. I want to parse a JSON string to a JSON object. The string contains an array of objects.

But `JSON.parse` is not converting any kinds of arrays successfully at all.
It returns an empty array for all arrays no matter what their content.

**EDIT:** It's not just a console problem. I save that parsed data in my database. And there also I just see an empty array. No magic tricks going on by the console.

**UPDATE:** Some external code has broken the Array definition. All array definitions now end up with an empty array. Debugging the cause, thanks for all responses.

**Examples:**

```
contacts = '{"data": [{"p": "", "e": "", "n": "Veera Sundar"}]}'  // This is my example JSON String. Rest are hit and trials.
> JSON.parse(contacts)
{ data: [] }
> a = '{"data": [{"p": ""}]}'
'{"data": [{"p": ""}]}'
> JSON.parse(a)
{ data: [] }
> a = '{"data": [1,2,3]}'
'{"data": [1,2,3]}'
> JSON.parse(a)
{ data: [] }
> a = '{"d": [1,2,3]}'
'{"d": [1,2,3]}'
> JSON.parse(a)
{ d: [] }
> a = '{"d": {"c":1}}'
'{"d": {"c":1}}'
> JSON.parse(a)
{ d: { c: 1 } }    // Works for objects
> a = '{"d": {"c":[1]}}'
'{"d": {"c":[1]}}'
> JSON.parse(a)
{ d: { c: [] } }
> a = '{"d": {"c":["b","e"]}}'
'{"d": {"c":["b","e"]}}'
> JSON.parse(a)
{ d: { c: [] } }
> a = '{"d": {"c":[{"b":1}]}}'
'{"d": {"c":[{"b":1}]}}'
> JSON.parse(a)
{ d: { c: [] } }
> a = '{"d": {"c":["undefined"]}}'
'{"d": {"c":["undefined"]}}'
> JSON.parse(a)
{ d: { c: [] } }`
```

Failed for everything else!!

Please let me know what am I doing wrong. All these examples work on regular console eg: Chrome console.

Comment: You might be misinterpreting the console output. Do you see that the array in `{ data: [] }` is hyperlinked in the console? Click it to open its contents.... Don't be mislead to think that the array is empty.

Comment: I just ran your code nothing's wrong, trincot is right maybe it's just showing you a misleading prompt. Here's my results :
> contacts = '{"data": [{"p": "", "e": "", "n": "Veera Sundar"}]}'
'{"data": [{"p": "", "e": "", "n": "Veera Sundar"}]}'
> JSON.parse(contacts)
{ data: [ { p: '', e: '', n: 'Veera Sundar' } ] }
>  a = '{"data": [{"p": ""}]}'
'{"data": [{"p": ""}]}'
> JSON.parse(a)
{ data: [ { p: '' } ] }

Comment: I understand, the chrome console does show the complete array, but the repl does not. 
I did the util inspection and it indeed shows the value, but this is bizzare:     > util.inspect(JSON.parse(contacts))
'{ data: [ { p: \'\', e: \'\', n: \'Veera Sundar\' } ] }'
> JSON.parse(contacts)
{ data: [] }
> a = JSON.parse(contacts)
{ data: [] }
> util.inspect(a)
'{ data: [ { p: \'\', e: \'\', n: \'Veera Sundar\' } ] }'

Comment: Even if console is not showing the value, somehow, I should be able to access it right: a.data returns an empty array

Comment: You can cross-check the parse result with `> JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(contacts));`.

Comment: Just figured out, my array is a problem. Some library or code is messing with the Array object. [1,2,3] simply returns an empty object. 
Trying to debug the problem. Thanks for the response everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out this was a bug in Node v6.0.0 where a filled array was represented as an empty array. 
Posted [this issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/6926) on git. It has been resolved on version 6.2.0 though.